# Setting up Linux bridge for all VLANs (tagged) when bridges for same VLANs (untagged) exist

Tags: linux, vlan, bridge, arp

**TL;DR:  Does anyone know how to get bridges associated with a VLAN (like virbr0.101) and a generic bridge that supports all VLANs (like virbr0) to co-exist?**

Sorry for the rambling backstory, but I'm building this up in layers for you.  I have a pretty generic (common) configuration for running KVM/LibVirt guests on a CentOS 7 server, where

"eno1" + "eno2" + "eno3" + "eno4" are bonded to become "bond0".  In my switch fabric I have a 803.2ad+LACP interface where I then configure 802.1Q trunk mode and add vlans 101, 102, 103, 104 to it.

Back in Linux, I then extend "bond0" with vlan interfaces:
"bond0.101", "bond0.102", "bond0.103", "bond0.104"

and finally, a set of bridges I use for the KVM guests:
"virbr0.101", "virbr0.102", "virbr0.103", "virbr0.104"

So far so good.  The guests use a bridge like "virbr0.101", and get access to VLAN 101 with untagged packets.  I configure all the guests with a simple "eth0" and they are NOT aware of what network segment they are operating in.  The bridge un-tags the packets to them.  I've been doing this for years.  Works like a dream.

---

Fast forward to now, and I have a new virtual firewall, where I want (need) to bring in the entire tagged VLAN trunk to that KVM guest.

Back on the server I naturally setup "virbr0" which is a bridge of "bond0" and create my virtual firewall.  I've done this with a bog-standard Centos machine as well, so let me use Linux jargon instead of Juniper Junos vSRX jargon for my explanation:

I have a CentOS 7 guest running on the same KVM host server as other guests, and this new guest is using "virbr0"; which I assume is the fully tagged bridge.  I then jump onto that new guest and configure an "eth0.101" interface with an IP address that should work on VLAN 101.  (Note: In reality, I'm going to want an "eth0.102", "eth0.103", and "eth0.104" running as well.)

---

I try a ping, and nothing works.  I can't reach anything on the VLAN 101 network.

Watching with tcpdump on the KVM server:

- virbr0 shows the outgoing ARP request, tagged with VLAN 101
- bond0 shows the outgoing ARP request, tagged with VLAN 101
- bond0 shows the incoming ARP response, tagged with VLAN 101
- bond0.101 shows the incoming ARP response, with no VLAN tag
- virbr0.101 shows the incoming ARP response, with no VLAN tag
- virbr0 does NOT show the incoming ARP response

So here is what I think is happening:

- the ARP response comes into the eno[1-4] interfaces and then the bond0 interface
- because it's VLAN 101, the kernel untags the traffic and sends it along to bond0.101 and virbr0.101
- meanwhile, the destination that needs the traffic -- virbr0 -- doesn't get it.

The traffic is shunted to the bond0.101/virbr0.101 and it never appears on virbr0, which is the bridge attached to bond0.

The net result is that the MAC address of eth0.101 on that "VLAN trunking guest" using virbr0 is never learned, and networking to/from that guest is broken.

---

I've searched high and low for a solution to this, and tried so many things I could fill a small book.  Does anyone know how to get bridges associated with a VLAN (like virbr0.101) and a generic bridge that supports all VLANs (like virbr0) to co-exist?

-Marc

Comment: *UPDATE*  I found another article that details the same problem at the end.  http://alesnosek.com/blog/2015/09/07/bridging-vlan-trunk-to-the-guest/

Comment: virbr0 should be made vlan aware by enabling vlan_filtering (with the command `ip link set/add ... type bridge vlan_filtering 1` ) and setting vlans with the command `bridge vlan`. I don't know how libvirt can handle this kind of setting